# Flask-restful: how to pass multi value params to a GET request?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

According to the [documentation](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html#multiple-values-lists) this is enough to pass in a multi value.

```
def __init__(self):
        super(LatestNewsAPI, self).__init__()
        self.req_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.req_parser.add_argument('date', type=str)
        self.req_parser.add_argument('media', action='append')
```

I'm passing trying to append two media into a list:

```
    rss_date_time = parser.parse('Tue, 15 Jan 2015 18:13:00 GMT')
    param = {'date': rss_date_time, 'media': 'GRD', 'media': 'IND'}
    url = '/api/v1.0/latest_news/?{0}'.format(urllib.urlencode(param))
    rv = self.client.get(url, headers={},
                         environ_base={'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1'})
```

However once I get there:

```
def get(self):
    args = self.req_parser.parse_args()
    date_str = args['date']
    date_time = parser.parse(date_str)
    media = args['media']
```

media contains only `[u'IND']`.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually an urllib problem in this case:

All I had to add was `doseq=True`

```
url = '/api/v1.0/latest_news/?{0}'.format(urllib.urlencode(param, doseq=True))
```

and change params to a list:

```
param = {'date': rss_date_time, 'media': ['GRD', 'IND']}
```

Now I get `[u'GRD', u'IND']`

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array:

```
 param = {'date': rss_date_time, 'media[]': ['GRD', 'IND']}
```

In Python they are actually called a `list`.

EDIT:

Likewise, you should use

```
media = args['media[]']
```

instead in the receiver side.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get `[u"['GRD', 'IND']"]`.  A list inside a list.  I also extended the question with more details.

Comment: I get now: `None` for media.  Did you see the update on my question? thanks

Comment: I doubt there's any need to put `[]` in the param names. Usually structures holding request data have a `getlist()` method (e.g. `request.form.getlist('some_key')`) which always return a list of all values passed for that key.